# Where can I add 'moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true' when using Vue-Moment?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, momentjs

I am using **vue-moment** installed via npm. I am launching a website soon and I can't risk changing the format of the dates as it's heavily required across the site, and don't want to break anything.

I've seen I can turn off warnings from moment.js by adding: **moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true**

However, as I am using vue-moment, I don't have a script file to change the settings. I have tried adding it to app.js and also to the components where moment is being used, however I still get the warning: **'Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format.'**

Is there a way I can suppress the warning in Vue.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be done as early as possible, right at the moment when the plugin is used:

```
import vueMoment from 'vue-moment';

Vue.use(vueMoment);
Vue.moment.suppressDeprecationWarnings = true;
```

Comment: I get 'Cannot set property 'suppressDeprecationWarnings' of undefined' when trying your solution

Comment: It's supposed to work, https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-euler-e88qc . I'm unaware of any conditions under which Vue.moment would be undefined after Vue.use(vueMoment). Use a debugger and make sure that vueMoment is plugin object.

Comment: OK I managed to get it to work now, I just had it set up differently compared to your example, but after matching your example it was fine. Thanks for your help!